# how to manage/design API access on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-endpoints, api-key

Let's say I have 3 datasets on Big Query -- Dataset A, Dataset B and Dataset C.

Also, I have 3 clients -- Client A, Client B and Client C.

And, I have a simple web app deployed in App Engine with an API, say, '/weather'.
The API simply writes a query from the client's input and reads and writes on the datasets, using Big Query APIs, and returns the result.

Clients A, B and C have their own API key so that they can use the weather API.

But I want to restrict API access such that Client A can only access Dataset A, Client B can only access Dataset B and Client C can only access Dataset C.

But, if Client A wants to access Dataset B too, I would also want to be able to easily grant Client A access to Dataset B without having to re-deploy my app.

I've done a lot of reading on Cloud Endpoints, App Engine and Big Query, but I couldn't really find any solutions.

What is the best way to achieve this hopefully maybe at Cloud Endpoints level or App Engine level or Big Query level? If not, at back-end Python level (I am using Flask)

The last resort I can think of would be, I would have to create a simple dictionary in a DB where the key is the API key and the value is a list of datasets that it can access. So, when a client hits the endpoint with their own API key, I have to check and see whether the client has access to the dataset or not.

But that would be quite an expensive operation and I would like to take care of this at GCP level or back-end python level.

Please let me know if there is any features on GCP that can help me achieve this.

Comment: If they have different service accounts, you can manage permissions in GCP IAM.

Comment: @SabriKaragönen I am sorry I am new to GCP. Could you please a little elaborate on it? Can I manage permissions at dataset level? If a service account has the permission to read and write to Big Query, doesn't it mean the service account can read and write to every dataset in Big Query?

Comment: You can limit service accounts permissions on project level and then grant on the dataset level. Even column-level permissions are possible. Just click the dataset in BigQuery, you'll see "Share Dataset" button. Using that menu, you can grant permissions.

Comment: @SabriKaragönen Thank you, I've looked at it and I really appreciate your suggestion. But the clients do not necessarily have service accounts. Big Query APIs will be used in the backend, not directly by the clients. The clients will just hit the endpoint, say from their browser or curl with valid API keys, which right now allows them to access every dataset in Big Query. Please let me know if I understood your suggestion wrong

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I would keep a dictionary as you said. You can choose to store it in Flask app, or in BigQuery table. Why do you think keeping APIkey - access data in BigQuery is an expensive operation?
Also, where do you store API keys?

Comment: @SabriKaragönen I am not sure if its actually expensive. But I just was just hoping to handle clients' requests at GCP levels or in Python except for using Big Query APIs, rather than going all over the place to serve the requests. I deployed my app in App Engine and am using Cloud Endpoints and store API keys for each client in my credentials. I thought this problem was pretty common so there would be some kind of features GCP provides or common practices that I could follow as opposed to me having to put logic in the backend. But having read the docs, I guess maybe not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform access control, you have 2 parts: Authentication and Authorization.

Cloud Endpoint is a good solution if you want to secure your API with a weak authentication secret (API Key). I [wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1).

Here, with your 3 clients, you will authenticate only 3 projects [(no USERS, only PROJECTS)](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/when-why-api-key). You also have the APIkey value in the query param. But it's **only authentication**.

If you want an authorization layer, to say *WHO have access to WHAT*, here, the client A has only access to the Dataset A, **you have to code it by yourselves.**

In my company, we keep these data into Firestore: serverless, quick, free (up to 50k read per day)